# Is solve correct in "solve a dilemma"?

Tags: word-usage

Is it correct to say "solve a dilemma"? If "solve" is correct only in regard to a "problem," what verb would be used in regard to a "dilemma"?

Comment: Yes, you solve dilemmas when you resolve them. A dilemma in all usages is a problem, and problems are solved.

Comment: Solve can be used anywhere where there is the slightest hint/smidgen of a problem. Quandary, dilemma, snafu, snag, problem, situation, equation, sum, piece, crisis, etc.

Comment: A search of literature (Google NGram Viewer) suggests "resolve" is the most common choice.

Comment: I suspect _resolve_ is the verb with the fewest extra assumptions. NB: the S is pronounced /z/ in _resolve_, whereas it's /s/ in _solve_.

Comment: Define *dilemma* and then we can solve/resolve  your question. *Dilemma* can mean *difficult problem*, in which case you can "solve" it. But classically it refers to a situation involving two unfavorable alternatives, and in this sense "resolve" is better.

Answer (score 4):

There would be nothing incorrect about solving a dilemma.  Since dilemma is a synonym for problem, I don't see an issue with this.

Other verbs may fit better with dilemma, but the context is important here.  For example:

> CASE 1:
>
> Verb/use case: The couple has been fighting for weeks, they have a dilemma to **work out.**
>
> CASE 2:
>
> Verb/use case: I called the host to **clear up** the dilemma of what time to arrive
>
> CASE 3:
>
> Verb/use case: My dilemma is that I don't know which direction to travel, I just need to **decide** and travel.

You can see how many more options there might be, but **solve** is certainly appropriate in regards to a **dilemma**

Comment: Is dilemma a true synonym for 'problem'? A dilemma is a situation in which you have to make a choice between 2 unpleasant options (the horns of the dilemma). While I agree that many people will use 'solve'; I think there are good grounds for 'escape' or 'get out of'.

Comment: I agree. I wouldn't refer to something that could be solved as a dilemma. Solving involves accepting the problem's constraints and working within those constraints. Dealing with a dilemma means you have to change the propositions because you can't satisfy all of the dilemma's propositions otherwise.

Comment: I think there are clear differences between "problem" and "dilemma", I like to use the word "issue" to describe either a cause or a result.  I believe you could 'solve' your dilemma by 'escaping'.  All in all, I believe there is a lot of gray area here relating to interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

You would probably be understood if you use "solve", but I think it's not the best choice.

A dilemma is a situation in which you must choose one of two options and the choice isn't easy. Faced with a dilemma, you should *make a choice*, not *solve a problem*.

Facing a dilemma is often considered a problem, especially if the choices seem equally unplausible; you may think of *making a choice* as a problem. But the dilemma itself is not a problem, it's a *situation*.

Some people use the term dilemma and mean "difficult problem", but this should be discouraged.

Instead of "solve", I would recommend "resolve" when referring to a dilemma. This word is related to solution, decision, settling.

See also [Usage discussion in Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dilemma).